Error: Native module "RNFBAppModule" not found. Re-check module install, linking, configuration, build and install steps
Can someone please help me fix this issue?
\>>re-install npm
\>>npx expo prebuild
\>>npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app
\>>npx expo install @react-native-firebase/auth
Did Gradle clean as well. But, this issue is still occurring. Please help me solve this issue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
